# Busy Indicator - Wicket is not defined

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

[Wicket 6.6.0]

I try to migrate my busy indicator script from 1.5.10 to 6.6.0 (based on [Generic Busy Indicator](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/generic-busy-indicator-for-both-ajax-and-non-ajax-submits.html)) and I always get the error **"Wicket is not defined"** at line ig. *Wicket.Event.subscribe(...)*.

Should I include manually any JavaScriptReference or Wicket does it automatically? I ask because there isn't any Wicket JS script references in my page source.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any Ajax behavior in your page ? If you don't, libraries are not contributed, you can however call `CoreLibrariesContributor.contribute(yourApplicationInstance, iHeaderResponse);` to add it into your page.

Comment: I haven't any behaviors yet. I wanted to figured out it first. I'll try your proposal.

Comment: I resolved it with merging resources into one bundle (based on this [Wicket Example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/resourceaggregation/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage;jsessionid=149E403017D88490DA7158FD26F972DD?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.resourcedecoration.HomePage&source=ResourceDecorationApplication.java))